# how do I release code on server?

Tags: linux, tortoisesvn

I have setup a svn server on my ec2 instance, and I checkedout the repository on my local machine. I added few files and committed those changes to the svn. 
Now when I log into my ec2 instance and check the repository, I do not find the files which I added and committed to svn.

Can someone please say me if I am missing any step.

Also, should I be merging my dev branch to trunk(live website points to trunk), so that the code is updated on the live website?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ask the managers? Or at least a colleague? :) Look for a TortoiseSVN tutorial on google. Really simple. You basically hit the "commit" button on the explorer menu, when you right-click on the working folder (the one which has the SVN'ed files, on your local machine).

Comment: I had committed my all file from the local

Answer (score 1):

1. A Subversion *repository* contains the compressed files in database form. You must create a *checkout* on the server, using `svn checkout`.
2. Ask your manager, we can't possibly know what they do.

Comment: Ok, I should have asked this, should I be merging the trunk with my development branch for releasing on the live website?

Comment: I don't know that either. That depends on how you (or your colleagues) have set up the branching policy for your development work.